# How can I limit the refresh rate on a website?

Tags: html, refresh, limit, meta, rate

I know, that it's possible to define a time after which a html website is automatically refreshed. But is there a way to limit this rate, so that for example one can not hold the F5 key pressed in order to refresh the website "continuously"? Either in the html file itself or maybe on the server with some settings especially for that file?

Comment: Sadly, you can't do this easily. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: "Either in the html file itself" — No

Comment: "maybe on the server" — Within some limits, but it's too broad of a problem for SO. You'd need to pick a programming language, identify sources of requests, record when requests from a given source were received etc.

Comment: Well I'm working on a project with google-maps, and there you have limits up to 2500 per day for some api and 25000 per day for some others. Since every 1000 refreshs cost in addition, I'd like to limit that refresh to once a minute, so nobody can "harm" or cause senseless costs for me, just by refreshing that website without any reason. That's the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you be able to prevent to reload the page, you can prevent user for always to close your web site unless he/she close browser and this will be so bothering.

Almost all you can do is to before reload page ask him are you sure? but you can't completely stop user to do that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "are you sure you want to leave?";
    }
</script>
```

or you can disable F5 on keyDown event `e` occured

```
if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
```

but If you want just limit the user from exceeding rate you can handle it by programming languages like PHP and ASP and save count of the visit in the user session and if exceed that number redirect him to some warning

Comment: Well I don't want to warn the user before leaving the website, but when they refresh it or load or reload the page. Actually I don't even want to warn them, but just to prevent them from loading the page, if they have already loaded that page less than minute before.

Comment: you can't do this.you can just disable F5 key and then the user won't be able to refresh the page with F5 key but he/she can reload the page by browsers button again.

Comment: if you be able to prevent to reload the page, you can prevent user for always to close you web site

Comment: Well I see. I will have to lead the user through another page, where I count its last call of that page and then either lead him to the targeted website or to a warning website.

Comment: yes, you can save a number of visited of the user in your pages in the user session and prevent him if he exceed the rate of course as I think yourself know this will be need programming languages like PHP or asp

Comment: Preventing someone from reloading a website doesn't mean to prevent him to close a page. The user should be able to close it, but not be able to open it before a certain time is being passed. That's something fully different.

Comment: I thought you mean just by javascript and HTML, Yes you can do it.I have updated my answer